# Disable Expect: 100-continue in AWS Java SDK v2

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a suspicion this header causes some compatibility issues for me where client timeout occurs when using `PutObjectRequest`.
I think the header is added through `software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.PutObjectInterceptor`.

How do I disable sending it to verify that theory? I could not find relevant option in client configuration?